# Single log in for multiple sites developed on different platform(s)

Tags: asp.net, sql, web-services, single-sign-on

Our company has  5  product sites developed using ASP.net,PHP,Flex, etc and most of them has common users.The requirement is to avoid multiple logins when the same user accessing these websites. We have different databases for authentication for each site.
Only registered users can able to go to the respective websites.

What would be the simple and easy approach  for doing this? Cookies doesn't work because of different platform(s) . I would like to use ASP.net/c#/SQL server for the development. There are different SSO's are available in the market ( SAML 2.0 with componentspace libraries), but not sure it is needed in our case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way this can be implemented is with Claims Based Authentication.

Basically, you will generate a token of some kind that would follow the user from system to system. (Encrypted, validated some how coming from a trusted source.)

Using that token, each system can authenticate the user and authorize access if successful.

This is similar to how some websites (like StackOverflow) will let you log-in with a Google or Facebook account without creating an individual account. Then when you login, FB or Google issues a token (aka claim) that you are who you say you are. Because StackOverflow trusts Google, they accept the Claim (promise) that you are, in fact you.

Comment: I will explain my scenario in detail.For an example there are 5 sites site 1,site 2, etc and user1 is a registered user for site1,site2 and site 5. User2 is registered for site1 and site4. When user1 logs in site1, should be able to go to site2 and site5 only without prompting for login. but should prompt for login for site 3 & 4. I think claims based authontication for users in one site grant access to the other site based on Trust of the identity provider site

Comment: Claim is not a T/F concept. Claims can contain list of sites, or applications. This is a good intro in to how this works in Windows: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423674.aspx
A Claim might contain a list of Roles for a User. An application can check a Claim and decide how to proceed (SSO or Login prompt).
Depending on your security needs, it's not trivial to design/implement this. Ex: "UserName|SourceApp|DestinationApp|ExpiresOn" - encrypted and Base64 encoded so it can be passed along through HTTP. Each website be able to decrypt the token, validate it, and let users in.